Type conflict with "filter" and "contains"
Error: ERROR: invalid: runtime error @27:6-27:64: filter: type conflict: string != int
Code: (sanitized, variable definitions removed)
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"
import "strings"
import "regexp"
import "array"

HOSTS = schema.tagValues(bucket: MY_BUCKET, tag: "hostname")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._value =~ SWITCH_SRC_REGEX and r._value !~ /-lab$/)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => PLANE_NUM(host: r._value) == 0)
  |> findColumn(fn: (key) => true, column: "_value")

from(bucket: MY_BUCKET)
  |> range(start: -1h)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "interface")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => ((r._field == "ifAlias" and r._value =~ SWITCH_DEST_REGEX) or r._field == "ifConnectorPresent"))
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field != "ifAlias")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => contains(value: r.hostname, set: HOSTS)) // line 27

Set up: Writing Flux queries in a Grafana instance to query influx buckets
Problem: Running "contains" in the main query always causes the above defined error, regardless of positioning or values passed to it
Even when replacing the filter on line 27 with hard coded values, the error still occurs. Examples:
HOSTS = ["host1", "host2", "host3"]
|> filter(fn: (r) => contains(value: "host1", set: HOSTS))

|> filter(fn: (r) => contains(value: "host1", set: ["host1", "host2", "host3"]))

To the best of my understanding, filter is looking for a bool, and contains returns a bool
Note: I have been able to get the contains to work on a simpler query, just looking at the filtering the tag values for the hostname key.
HOSTS = ["host1", "host2", "host3"]
schema.tagValues(bucket: MY_Bucket, tag: "hostname")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => contains(value: r._value, set: HOSTS))

